# FiddlerCore with Selenium proxy settings

Tags: c#, selenium, https, proxy, fiddlercore

I use FiddlerCore to capture HTTP traffic when performing web UI tests with Selenium (C#) ChromeDriver. I have finally managed to get it working by trial and error, but need a hint on why my solution works and the logical way (for me) doesn't.

I configure the fiddler proxy as:

```
CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = false;

FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetBoolPref("fiddler.network.streaming.abortifclientaborts", true);

var startupSettings =
    new FiddlerCoreStartupSettingsBuilder()
        .ListenOnPort(0)
        .DecryptSSL()
        .OptimizeThreadPool()
        .Build();

FiddlerApplication.Startup(startupSettings);
HttpPort = FiddlerApplication.oProxy.ListenPort;
FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("Created HTTP endpoint listening on port {0}", HttpPort);

secureEndpoint = FiddlerApplication.CreateProxyEndpoint(HttpsPort, true, Host);
if (secureEndpoint != null)
{
    HttpsPort = secureEndpoint.ListenPort;
    FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("Created secure endpoint listening on port {0}, using a HTTPS certificate for '{1}'",HttpsPort, Host);
}

CertMaker.trustRootCert();
```

This basically follows the demo project provided for FiddlerCore. Note, that the proxy is not registered as system proxy.

Then, ChromeDriver is configured as:

```
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.Proxy = new Proxy()
{
    HttpProxy = $"{SkicoProxy.Host}:{SkicoProxy.HttpPort}",
    SslProxy = $"{SkicoProxy.Host}:{SkicoProxy.HttpPort}"
};
_driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
```

What doesn't work, although I would expect it to is:

```
options.Proxy = new Proxy()
{
    HttpProxy = $"{SkicoProxy.Host}:{SkicoProxy.HttpPort}",
    SslProxy = $"{SkicoProxy.Host}:{SkicoProxy.HttpsPort}" // HTTPS PORT INSTEAD HTTP PORT
};
```

Still, if I do not configure the endpoint in Fiddler, SSL websites are shown as unsafe in Chrome.

Why doesn't SSL traffic needs to be routed through the according endpoint and why does it even work if it is not proxied through the secure endpoint?

Comment: Fiddler is using an intermediate SSL certificate to encrypt the https traffic (some kind of "man in the middle" attack)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes, I am ware of this. I would even understand if it worked without configuring the secure endpoint. But it doesn't: I need to configure the endpoint, but I don't need to use it. That is what irritates me...

Comment: what's the value of "HttpsPort"?  That part looks a little odd cause you're setting it in the constructor and then reading it back to itself later.  443?

Comment: also when you get the unsafe error, look at the cert... what does it say about the error?

Comment: @pcalkins Due to selenium type naming, the code is misleading: Proxy() is the selenium proxy settings object, not the actual proxy server. The ports are set by the fiddler server correctly (not shown in the code above).